# Backbone - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'call'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-model

I am trying to save a model, I can save the first model fine, however if I save one model and then another straight afterwards -  I get the following error,

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'call'`

What would be causing this error?

My save code looks like this,

```
GroupModalHeaderView.prototype.save = function(e) {

  var $this = this;
  this.collection = new app.GroupCollection();

  if(this.$("#group-name").val() !== "") {
    this.collection.add(this.model,{
      merge: true
    });
  }

  this.model.save({
    name: this.$("#group-name").val(),
    async: false,
    wait: true
  }, {
    success: function() {

      var GroupList = new app.GroupListView({
        model: $this.model,
        collection: $this.collection
      });

      var modal = new app.GroupModalView({
        model: $this.model,
        collection: $this.collection
      });

      $this.collection.on("change",  GroupList.render(), this);
      $this.collection.on("change",  modal.render(), this);
      //return $this.cancel();
    }
  });
};
```

And my Model code looks like this,

```
    (function() {
  var Group, GroupSearchModel,
    __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
    __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

  Group = (function(_super) {

    __extends(Group, _super);

    function Group() {
      return Group.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    Group.prototype.urlRoot = config.base + "api/group/groups";

    Group.prototype.defaults = {
      user_id: "",
      name: "New Group",
      email: "",
      url: "",
      telephone: "",
      mobile: "",
      fax: "",
      people: ""
    };

    Group.prototype.idAttribute = "id";

    return Group;

  })(app.BaseModel);

  GroupSearchModel = (function(_super) {

    __extends(GroupSearchModel, _super);

    function GroupSearchModel() {
      return GroupSearchModel.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    return GroupSearchModel;

  })(app.BaseModel);

  this.app = window.app || {};

  this.app.Group = Group;

  this.app.GroupSearchModel = GroupSearchModel;

}).call(this);
```

I am assuming that is has something to do with the `.call(this)` at the end of my model?

Comment: Based on your code, you REALLY need to read this article about how to structure Backbone views and models: http://alexkinnee.com/2013/12/optimal-use-of-backbone-js-model-events-and-mvc-structure/

:)

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of whackiness in your code, but my first guess is that this mistake is causing your current problem. When binding event handlers, you usually want to **reference but not EXCUTE** the handler function. So instead of `GroupList.render()`  (with the parenthesese) which is executing a function, you want `GroupList.render` (without the parenthesese) which is 
just referencing it without execution.

```
$this.collection.on("change",  GroupList.render, this);
$this.collection.on("change",  modal.render, this);
//return $this.cancel();
```